# Is a 3 column SQL index used when the middle column can be anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Trying to prove something out currently to see if adding an index is necessary.

If I have an index on columns A,B,C and I create a query that in the where clause is only explicitly utilizing A and C, will I get the benefit of the index?

In this scenario imagine the where clause is like this:

```
A = 'Q' AND (B is not null OR B is null) AND C='G'
```

I investigated this in Oracle using EXPLAIN PLAN and it doesn't seem to use the index. Also, from my understanding of how indexes are created and used it won't be able to benefit because the index can't leverage column B due to the lack of specifics.

Currently looking at this in either MSSQL or ORACLE. Not sure if one optimizes differently than the other.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Oracle can make use of such an index using a skip-scan algorithm.  I don't think SQL Server has implemented this.

Comment: `B IS NOT NULL OR B IS NULL` should be trivially filtered out as an expression that's always true, by any optimizer worth its salt, and so it should have no impact on the query at all. (Even if it did, whatever behavior it used to implement it could be no more efficient than when `B` isn't filtered at all.) My simple empirical tests suggests SQL Server indeed simplifies this clause to nothing.

Comment: Also, in SQL Server 2017 at least, an index on `A, B, C` *will* be used -- there will be a filtered seek to all rows with `A = 'Q'`, using `C = 'G'` as the filter predicate. I haven't looked at whether this filter on `C` is implemented any more efficiently than a linear scan (I doubt it), but the index *is* considered, and if it is covering it will still improve access times over having only an index on `A`.

Comment: Is having an index only on columns A and B just as efficient in this case as having one on A,B, and C? Currently there is an index on A and B. Thanks for the responses. Very helpful.

Comment: Still SQL server only: if the index is on `A,B`, and your query is on `A,C`, it is no better than an index only on `A`, because a clustered index lookup will still be required to get back `C`. Whether the index will be used at all depends on whether the optimizer considers a table scan faster than an index seek + series of clustered index lookups. In all cases, however, theoretical considerations never beat actual measurements, so if you're asking this because you really need to know for a production system, do yourself a favor and always measure with actual data and actual indexes.

Comment: Of course! I have done some examination in editors and actually ran the updates in a performance environment and didn't see a noted benefit. I wondered if there was something I was missing though in the theory of it. SQL is tricky because it is all dependent on the optimizations made by type and version of the product you are using. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 

SQL> create table t$ (a integer not null, b integer, c integer, d varchar2(100 char));

Table created

SQL> insert into t$ select rownum, rownum, rownum, lpad('0', '1', 100) from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

1000000 rows inserted

SQL> create index t$i on t$(a, b, c);

Index created

SQL> analyze table t$ estimate statistics;

Table analyzed

SQL> explain plan for select * from t$ where a = 128 and c = 128;

Explained

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3274478018
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |      |     1 |    13 |     4   (0)
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T$   |     1 |    13 |     4   (0)
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | T$I  |     1 |       |     3   (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   2 - access("A"=128 AND "C"=128)
       filter("C"=128)
15 rows selected
```

Any question?

Comment: Just to clarify, this shows that even when only columns A and C are used the 3 column index is still used? At least initially to filter by A and then scan for C? What happens when a gibberish B conditional is added to this?

Comment: At my system it would be the same. Oracle uses cost-based optimizer so generated plan isn't absolutely stable, somebody other can execute this script and get different result. But this shows that 3-column index has a chance to be used in such case. It depends, I guess, of A column selectiveness first of all.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thank you! This is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the B + tree structure of the index, then the answer is as follows
The left-hand side of the index, including the first inequality, will go to Seek Predicate, the rest in Predicate in queryplan.

For example read http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys